# javascript / html / CSS text formatting issue. document.getElementById("booksFound").innerHTML = foundStr;

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two buttons that when pushed display a string. I am not sure how to format this string. I would like for them to be in an unordered list within the confines of the blue boxes.

FYI:

if you are working toward a t-shirt for hacktoberfest then I have my code on github at https://github.com/Kat35601/Search_a_String.git else see below.

```js
var found=[],books=["Genesis","Exodus","Leviticus","Numbers","Deuteronomy","Joshua","Judges","Ruth","Samuel","Samuel","Kings","Kings","Chronicles","Chronicles","Ezra","Nehemiah","Esther","Job","Psalms","Proverbs","Ecclesiastes","Song of Solomon","Isaiah","Jeremiah","Lamentations","Ezekiel","Daniel","Hosea","Joel","Amos","Obadiah","Jonah","Micah","Nahum","Habakkuk","Zephaniah","Haggai","Zechariah","Malachi","Matthew","Mark","Luke","John","Acts","Romans","Corinthians","Galatians","Ephesians","Philippians","Colossians","Thessalonians","Timothy","Timothy","Titus","Philemon","Hebrews","James","Peter","Peter","John","Jude","Revelation"],puzzle="Can you find the names of 25 books of the Bible in this paragraph? This is a most remarkable puzzle.Someone found it in the seat pocket on a flight from Los Angeles to Honolulu, keeping himself occupied for hours.One man from Illinois worked on this while fishing from his john boat. Roy Clark studied it while playing his banjo. Elaine Victs mentioned it in her column once. One woman judges the job to be so involving, she brews a cup of tea to help calm her nerves. There will be some names that are really easy to spot that’s a fact. Some people will soon find themselves in a jam, especially since the book names are not necessarily capitalized. The truth is, from answerswe get, we are forced to admit it usually takes a minister or scholar to see some of them at the worst. Something in our genes is responsible for the difficulty we have. Those able to find all of them will hear great lamentations from those who have to be shown. One revelation may help, books like! Timothy and Samuel may occur without their numbers. And punctuation or spaces in the middle are normal. A chipper attitude will help you compete. Remember, there are 25 books of the Bible lurking somewhere in this paragraph. Greater love hath no man than this, that a man lay down his life for his friends. John 15:13.";

//Search results for books and return those found

puzzle = puzzle.replace(/\W/g, '').toLowerCase();

for (let i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
  const index = puzzle.search(books[i].toLowerCase());
  if (index >= 0 && found.indexOf(books[i]) == -1) {
    found.push(books[i]);
  }
}

//show all bookes of the Bible

function showBooks() {
  var x = document.getElementById("thebooks");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block"
    var str = books.toString();
    document.getElementById("thebooks").innerHTML = str;
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
// show books that are found in the paragraph

function foundBooks() {
  var f = document.getElementById("booksFound");
  if (f.style.display === "none") {
    f.style.display = "block"
    var foundStr = found.toString();
    document.getElementById("booksFound").innerHTML = foundStr;
  } else {
    f.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#canvas {
     width: 800px;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     margin: auto;
}
 h1 {
     text-align: center;
}
 #thebooks {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 50px 0;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: lightblue;
     margin-top: 20px;
     display: none;
}
 #booksFound {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 50px 0;
     text-align: center;
     background-color: lightblue;
     margin-top: 20px;
     display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="canvas">
    <h1> Can you find 25 books of the Bible in the paragraph below.</h1>
    <p>Can you find the names of 25 books of the Bible in this paragraph? This is a most remarkable puzzle. Someone found it in the seat pocket on a flight from Los Angeles to Honolulu, keeping himself occupied for hours. One man from Illinois worked on this while fishing from his john boat. Roy Clark studied it while playing his banjo. Elaine Victs mentioned it in her column once. One woman judges the job to be so involving, she brews a cup of tea to help calm her nerves. There will be some names that are really easy to spot that’s a fact. Some people will soon find themselves in a jam, especially since the book names are not necessarily capitalized. The truth is, from answers we get, we are forced to admit it usually takes a minister or scholar to see some of them at the worst. Something in our genes is responsible for the difficulty we have. Those able to find all of them will hear great lamentations from those who have to be shown. One revelation may help, books like! Timothy and Samuel may occur without their numbers. And punctuation or spaces in the middle are normal. A chipper attitude will help you compete. Remember, there are 25 books of the Bible lurking somewhere in this paragraph. Greater love hath no man than this, that a man lay down his life for his friends. John 15:13.</p>
    <input id="booksButton" type="button" value="Books of The Bible" onclick="showBooks();" />
    <input id="foundButton" type="button" value="Books Found in the Paragraph" onclick="foundBooks();" />
    <div id="thebooks">
    </div>
    <div id="booksFound">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So loop over it and build a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run for loop and add each word in `li` tag.

```
for (var book in strArr) {
    str += "<li>" + strArr[book] + "</li>";
}
```

For found books instead of `found.push(books[i]);` use `found.push("<li>" + books[i] + "</li>");`

```js
var found=[],books=["Genesis","Exodus","Leviticus","Numbers","Deuteronomy","Joshua","Judges","Ruth","Samuel","Samuel","Kings","Kings","Chronicles","Chronicles","Ezra","Nehemiah","Esther","Job","Psalms","Proverbs","Ecclesiastes","Song of Solomon","Isaiah","Jeremiah","Lamentations","Ezekiel","Daniel","Hosea","Joel","Amos","Obadiah","Jonah","Micah","Nahum","Habakkuk","Zephaniah","Haggai","Zechariah","Malachi","Matthew","Mark","Luke","John","Acts","Romans","Corinthians","Galatians","Ephesians","Philippians","Colossians","Thessalonians","Timothy","Timothy","Titus","Philemon","Hebrews","James","Peter","Peter","John","Jude","Revelation"],puzzle="Can you find the names of 25 books of the Bible in this paragraph? This is a most remarkable puzzle.Someone found it in the seat pocket on a flight from Los Angeles to Honolulu, keeping himself occupied for hours.One man from Illinois worked on this while fishing from his john boat. Roy Clark studied it while playing his banjo. Elaine Victs mentioned it in her column once. One woman judges the job to be so involving, she brews a cup of tea to help calm her nerves. There will be some names that are really easy to spot that’s a fact. Some people will soon find themselves in a jam, especially since the book names are not necessarily capitalized. The truth is, from answerswe get, we are forced to admit it usually takes a minister or scholar to see some of them at the worst. Something in our genes is responsible for the difficulty we have. Those able to find all of them will hear great lamentations from those who have to be shown. One revelation may help, books like! Timothy and Samuel may occur without their numbers. And punctuation or spaces in the middle are normal. A chipper attitude will help you compete. Remember, there are 25 books of the Bible lurking somewhere in this paragraph. Greater love hath no man than this, that a man lay down his life for his friends. John 15:13.";

//Search results for books and return those found

puzzle = puzzle.replace(/\W/g, '').toLowerCase();
for (let i = 0; i < books.length; i++) {
  const index = puzzle.search(books[i].toLowerCase());
  if (index >= 0 && found.indexOf(books[i]) == -1) {
    found.push("<li>" + books[i] + "</li>");
  }
}

//show all bookes of the Bible

function showBooks() {
  var x = document.getElementById("thebooks");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    var strArr = books.toString().split(",");
    var str = "";
    for (var book in strArr) {
        str += "<li>" + strArr[book] + "</li>";
    }
    document.getElementById("thebooks").innerHTML = str;
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
// show books that are found in the paragraph

function foundBooks() {
  var f = document.getElementById("booksFound");
  if (f.style.display === "none") {
    f.style.display = "block"
    var foundStr = found.toString().split(",").join("");
    document.getElementById("booksFound").innerHTML = foundStr;
  } else {
    f.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#canvas {
     width: 800px;
     font-family: sans-serif;
     margin: auto;
}
 h1 {
     text-align: center;
}
 #thebooks {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 50px 0;
     background-color: lightblue;
     margin-top: 20px;
     display: none;
}
 #booksFound {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 50px 0;
     background-color: lightblue;
     margin-top: 20px;
     display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <div id="canvas">
    <h1> Can you find 25 books of the Bible in the paragraph below.</h1>
    <p>Can you find the names of 25 books of the Bible in this paragraph? This is a most remarkable puzzle. Someone found it in the seat pocket on a flight from Los Angeles to Honolulu, keeping himself occupied for hours. One man from Illinois worked on this while fishing from his john boat. Roy Clark studied it while playing his banjo. Elaine Victs mentioned it in her column once. One woman judges the job to be so involving, she brews a cup of tea to help calm her nerves. There will be some names that are really easy to spot that’s a fact. Some people will soon find themselves in a jam, especially since the book names are not necessarily capitalized. The truth is, from answers we get, we are forced to admit it usually takes a minister or scholar to see some of them at the worst. Something in our genes is responsible for the difficulty we have. Those able to find all of them will hear great lamentations from those who have to be shown. One revelation may help, books like! Timothy and Samuel may occur without their numbers. And punctuation or spaces in the middle are normal. A chipper attitude will help you compete. Remember, there are 25 books of the Bible lurking somewhere in this paragraph. Greater love hath no man than this, that a man lay down his life for his friends. John 15:13.</p>
    <input id="booksButton" type="button" value="Books of The Bible" onclick="showBooks();" />
    <input id="foundButton" type="button" value="Books Found in the Paragraph" onclick="foundBooks();" />
    <div id="thebooks">
    </div>
    <div id="booksFound">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```